# Office365 Calendar Events For Team Meeting

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, office365

I am developing one application in ASP.NET with office365 REST API. I need to schedule a team event in office365 but before scheduling that event i need to check the available time of all team members. If a slot is free then only i need to setup a event for the team.

Lets assume i have 3 members team like , user1@someone.com , user2@someone.com, user3@clientone.com . I need to check the available times of all members on team and needs to show only compatable times. Lets assume user1 have a schedule meeting at 9:00am - 9:30 am then i need to hide that time why because user1 is not having free time.

How can i do this? Any idea?

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Find Meeting Times (=Exchange FreeBusy) is in preview https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Findmeetingtimespreview but you should be able to use it via https://outlook.office.com/api/beta

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Can i get all members data from these??

Comment: It works the same as FreeBusy in Outlook or OWA so if these members are within your tenant it should work okay. Its a preview API so best thing to do is try it yourself and then feedback what you like and don't like about it there also a demo in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcN5f4L-p4E

Comment: Actually i am looking for multi-tenant not single tenant.

Comment: So have you actually tried to use it ?? It uses the FreeBusy functionality provided to by Exchange. If freebusy has been federated then it will work cross tenant https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ehlro/2015/03/26/enable-freebusy-information-between-the-office-365-users-from-two-different-tenants-when-the-autodiscover-of-one-of-them-is-pointing-on-premise/

Answer (score 0):

Finally i tried to use the free/busy code . My code as follows... I am following this procedure but i don't know either it is correct or not. I have office365 account and by passing credentials silently i am creating exchange server service. After that i am passing different domain attendee information as ORGANIZER and REQUIRED as follows. But it is returning all values not skipping any scheduled meetings for those users.

Lets assume user1@domain.com is ORGANIZER and user2@anotherdomain.com is REQUIRED for meeting . User1 have meeting scheduled at 7:00-7:30pm on daily basis but when i executed the following script it shows me 7:00-7:30pm as available for meeting. It supposed to block that time. Can you suggest somechanges to code and am i proceeding in correct way??

```
private static void GetSuggestedMeetingTimes(ExchangeService service)
    {


        List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();

        attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
        {
            SmtpAddress = "user1@mydomain.com",
            AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Organizer
        });

        attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
        {
            SmtpAddress = "user2@anotherdomain.com",
            AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required
        });

        // Specify options to request free/busy information and suggested meeting times.
        AvailabilityOptions availabilityOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
        availabilityOptions.GoodSuggestionThreshold = 49;
        availabilityOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 0;
        availabilityOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 40;
        // Note that 60 minutes is the default value for MeetingDuration, but setting it explicitly for demonstration purposes.
        availabilityOptions.MeetingDuration = 30;
        availabilityOptions.MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Good;
        availabilityOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
        availabilityOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.FreeBusy;

        // Return free/busy information and a set of suggested meeting times. 
        // This method results in a GetUserAvailabilityRequest call to EWS.
        GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees,
                                                                         availabilityOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow,
                                                                         AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions,
                                                                         availabilityOptions);
        // Display suggested meeting times. 
        Console.WriteLine("Availability for {0} and {1}", attendees[0].SmtpAddress, attendees[1].SmtpAddress);
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (Suggestion suggestion in results.Suggestions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Suggested date: {0}\n", suggestion.Date.ToShortDateString());
            Console.WriteLine("Suggested meeting times:\n");
            foreach (TimeSuggestion timeSuggestion in suggestion.TimeSuggestions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0} - {1}\n",
                                  timeSuggestion.MeetingTime.ToShortTimeString(),
                                  timeSuggestion.MeetingTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(availabilityOptions.MeetingDuration)).ToShortTimeString());



            }
        }

        int i = 0;

        // Display free/busy times.
        foreach (AttendeeAvailability availability in results.AttendeesAvailability)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Availability information for {0}:\n", attendees[i].SmtpAddress);

            foreach (CalendarEvent calEvent in availability.CalendarEvents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tBusy from {0} to {1} \n", calEvent.StartTime.ToString(), calEvent.EndTime.ToString());
            }

            i++;
        }
```